# Objection-find No way to search in postgres arrays ( array column not json or jsonb)

Tags: postgresql, objection.js

I have one region array in column. When i am trying to findquery and applying query into it. Searching inside array column doesn't work when array have more than one entry.

Case 1. array column(i.e. region) is [NA-US] and search query is region={NA-US}. It works

Case 2. array column(i.e. region) is [NA-US, AS-US] and search query is region={NA-US}. It doesn't works.

I tried with any operator in where clause by removing region from query. It gives error operator any is not supported.

Comment: From which layer do you get the error regarding the ANY operator `where 'NA-US' = ANY(the_array_column)` will work in SQL. Another option would be `where the_array_column @> array['NA_US']`

Comment: Your comment help me to create a filter in objection-find